# error: R code interpreted as math formula in LyX

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

I type this code in LyX:

```
<<>>=
data$y <- data$x
@
```

This code makes an error, because the "$$" makes the content inside them interpreted as a math formula. Is there anyway to contour this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code in a TeX box. To do this, highlight all of the text and go to Insert > TeX Code (default shortcut is ctrl + l).

If you happen to be using LyX 2.1 beta, go to help > specific manuals > knitr to see an example.

Don't forget that you must have the module loaded. To do this, go to Document > Settings > Modules